# Accessing a std::map via a property getter returns garbage values

Tags: c++, ios, llvm, objective-c++, xcode5.1

I have ran into this problem on a project and have boiled it down to the following sample code:

```
#import <map>

typedef std::map<int, int> exampleMap;
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) exampleMap map;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)iterateWithSelf:(id)sender
{
    for (exampleMap::iterator iter = self.map.begin(); iter != self.map.end(); ++iter)
    {
        NSLog(@"We should never hit this line as map is empty");
    }
}
- (IBAction)iterateWithIVar:(id)sender
{
    for (exampleMap::iterator iter = _map.begin(); iter != _map.end(); ++iter)
    {
        NSLog(@"We should never hit this line as map is empty");
    }
}

@end
```

`- iterateWithIVar:` executes fine and nothing is logged to the console.
`- iterateWithSelf:` goes into the for loop, prints a line to the console and then crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

I then tried inserting...     `self.map.insert(std::pair<int, int>(0, 1));` appears to affect nothing while `_map.insert(std::pair<int, int>(0, 1));` adds an iteration to `iterateWithIvar`

Any ideas?

Comment: http://openradar.appspot.com/17001373

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important thing to note is that `self.map` sends a message (i.e. calls a method).  *It does not access a structure member*.  It’s like the following C++ code:

```
class ViewController {
public:
  typedef std::map<int, int> ExampleMap;

private:
  ExampleMap _map;

public:
  ExampleMap map() { return _map; }
  setMap(const ExampleMap &o) { _map = o; }
};
```

followed by

```
for (auto iter = vc.map().begin(); iter != vc.map().end(); ++iter) {
  std::cerr << "We should never hit this line as map is empty" << std::endl;
}
```

That being the case, this is "expected behaviour". C++ objects are copied by value. Which means that every time you call `self.map` you get a new copy of your map. As it is invalid C++ to use iterators from one map to iterate over a second map, you get a crash.

In the second case, you directly access the instance variable, so you're dealing with the same object every time. There are several workarounds:

1. Rewrite your class to provide accessors (e.g. `-(int) numberOfItemsInMap`, `-mapItemForKey:` etc.) which directly access the ivar.
2. Change the accessors to no longer copy: Use an ivar for the map, manually write your own getter to return a pointer or reference to the map (If you use a pointer, you can declare the accessors as pointer properties anyway, but then use operator new to create it in your constructor).
3. Rewrite `-iterateWithSelf:` to take an explicit copy of the map and then iterate over that (this is probably going to be inefficient, assuming that `std::map` is an efficient container for your use-case).

The first is probably the cleanest approach, as it also ensures your ObjC object is always aware of accesses/changes made to the underlying map, whereas directly exposing a pointer to the map allows anyone to modify it without your knowledge.

Comment: AHA!  Now I've read this answer and wrote a little bit of test code this is very obvious.  Too much working exclusively with pointers in OBJC.  Thanks